# Hartshorne, II, Theorem $8.15$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field (algebraically closed if you like) and let $A$ be a finitely generated $k$-algebra with the nilradical being prime. Set $X=\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ and let $x\in X$ be a closed point corresponding to the maximal prime $\mathfrak{m}$.

In the light of what Hartshorne writes in the first line of the proof of $\textbf{Theorem 8.15}$, Chapter II, we have

$$
\operatorname{dim}(A_{\mathfrak{m}})=\operatorname{dim}(A).
$$

> $\textbf{Theorem 8.15}$ Let $X$ be an irreducible separated scheme of finite type over an algebraically closed field $k$. Then $\Omega_{X/k}$ is a locally free sheaf of rank $n=\operatorname{dim}(X)$ if and only if $X$ is a nonsingular variety over $k$

$\textit{Proof.}$ If $x\in X$ is a closed point, then the local ring $B=\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ has dimension $n$.

This confuses me, he doesn't assume $X$ to be integral, so we cannot apply the dimension formula
$$
\operatorname{dim}(A)=\operatorname{dim}(A_{\mathfrak{p}})+\operatorname{dim}(A/\mathfrak{p}).
$$
What is going on here? In general the lengths of maximal chains of prime ideals are not the same.

Comment: Dimension is defined in the case of $X$ irreducible, not just $X$ integral.

Comment: @KReiser I didn't deny this. But what is the reason for $\operatorname{dim}(A)=\operatorname{dim}(A_{\mathfrak{m}})$?

Comment: The above comments says that if $Q$ is $P$-primary, then $\dim A/Q = \dim A/ \sqrt{Q} = \dim A/ P$.